# Requesting a symbol, please assist

Tags: formatting, symbols

I hope it's not out of the line to ask for a symbol like this, but
I've been looking for a very simple symbol that I just can't find anywhere!

I want it to be like

```
       ⊣
```

but instead of the | at the end I'd like a    (
So like a --(  but in one symbol.
I've looked in so many places, and the things people do with text is crazy, yet this very simple combination - I couldn't find. >.<
I hope you can help me :)
cheers

Comment: Like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Isp.png)? Perhaps smaller...

Comment: Where did you find that symbol? What does it stand for? Do you have some reference where this is used? I can't find it in the unicode but if you know some real usage for this, one could recommend to insert it. If you have some bigger image showing how it is used, we would be thankful for that.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! That is exactly what I was looking for, Werner! Where can I get it?

Comment: How large is this symbol supposed to be? Should the parenthesis be the size of a "normal" parenthesis, or smaller? If so, how much smaller? How will this symbol be used: as a relational operator, a binary operator, or something different altogether?

Comment: Mico, thanks for your reply. It's purely for visual purposes, I need it for an art project of mine. A regular sized parenthesis is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could create the symbol with a LaTeX macro. In the code below, it's called `\dashrparen` ('dash and right parenthesis') and is assumed to be a relational operator. If it's a binary operator, use `\mathbin` instead. Or, `\mathord` if it's just an "ordinary" symbol...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\dashrparen{\mathrel{-\mkern-3.7mu(}}
\begin{document}
$A \dashrparen B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have absolutely no knowledge about these things. I was hoping for a copy and paste-able version

Comment: @Illustrator - Is there something stopping you from copying and pasting the symbol from a pdf file to any location?

Comment: Of course not. Was there a pdf file somewhere that I missed? If so, my mistake.

Comment: @Illustrator - Do you know how to compile the code with pdflatex to *create* a pdf file?

Comment: I do not. I have come here hoping to find people with knowledge of such things. I'm completely illiterate as far as these things go, sorry.

Comment: @Illustrator - This site is about using TeX and friends to create various things -- usually, documents. If you don't already have a TeX distribution installed on your system, you'd have to start with that. TeXlive can run on many platforms; MikTeX is another distribution, which runs only on Windows systems. (There are *many* postings on this site related to installing a TeX installation.) Have you checked the [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) site? As you haven't told us anything about the software you may be using, I can't offer further suggestions at this point.

Comment: Suppose I'll gear myself up and try and create the symbol on my own, using your guidelines, then :)

Comment: Ah this is gonna take a little bit. Can't you just copy and paste the symbol in the comments please?

Comment: Mico I'm not using any special software, I just need this for... similar to ASCII art purposes

Comment: @Illustrator This symbol does not exists in unicode so there will be no copy-paste-solution as you desire. As you are not using TeX until now and just need this symbol, I would recommend to install Inkscape and to draw that little thing. You will be able to export it as pdf, svg, png... That is most you can get.

Comment: So no way to use the symbol in regular text, like here?